# A semisimple ring with a finite number of left maximal ideals

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, noncommutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings, division-ring

Let $R$ be a semisimple ring with a finite number of left maximal ideals.  (Here "semisimple" means that the Jacobson radical is zero.)

Show that $R \cong R_1 \times ... \times R_n$

Such that every $R_i$ is a division ring or $R_i \cong M_{n_i}(K_i)$ for a finite field $K_i$

---

I'm completely stuck. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about Wedderburn-Artin theorem?

Comment: Yes. But can't think of ways to use it here.

Comment: Start by showing that $R$ is an Artinian semisimple ring. Then it will be isomorphic to a direct product $M_{n_1}(D_1)\times...\times M_{n_r}(D_r)$ where $D_1,...,D_r$ are division rings. The finite division rings among $D_1,...,D_r$ are actually finite fields by a well known theorem. And if some $D_i$ is infinite, show that we must have $n_i=1$, and so $M_{n_i}(D_i)\cong D_i$ is a division ring. (use the assumption that $R$ has only finitely many left maximal ideals)

Comment: Thank you! can you give me a reference for the "well known theorem" about the finite division rings ?

Comment: Every finite division ring is a field, this is Wedderburn's little theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Oh of course :)

Comment: can you give more direction for the infinite case?
also semisimple ring is not always an artinian?

Comment: No, semisimple doesn't mean Artinian. To show $R$ is Artinian you also have to use the fact that is has finitely many left maximal ideals. And for the last part, check in general what are the left ideals of $M_n(D)$. (I believe this was discussed on this forum before)

Comment: is it true that $M_n(D) , n >0 $ has an infinitely many number of maximal left ideal? how can i show that?

Comment: If $n>1$ and $D$ is infinite then yes. As I said, look up what are the left ideals of $M_n(D)$. You'll see they correspond to subspaces of $D^n$ over $D$.

Comment: @Mark A preponderance of ring theory literature does use "semisimple" to refer to what some people call "semisimple artinian rings," so I don't think it's possible to dismiss their comment entirely that way.

Comment: @MZG When you say "semisimple" do you mean the Jacobson radical is zero or do you mean every submodule is a summand?

Comment: Jacobson radical is zero

Comment: @MZG In a case of clarification like this one should always always always include the clarification by editing the post too.

Comment: @MZG Perhaps you can update your question body with what you've learned so far so that it is more than a problem statement? It is likely to gather close votes, in its current state.

Comment: @MZG if you haven't updated this by tomorrow, I think I'll probably cast the first vote to close awaiting improvement.